# Connection timeout on Amazon Linux ami

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2

Created a Linux ami instance in Amazon. It worked fine for a day. But now (2 days later) I keep getting connection timeout. Able to connect via PuTTY though. 
When I try to access the site or try to connect via ftp the connection keeps failing.

Comment: The fact that you can connect via PuTTY says that the server is "alive". If you haven't changed any settings on the Security Group, then it is likely that your services are not running. Can you access them once you have connected via PuTTY? For example, try `curl localhost` to retrieve the default web server page.

Comment: curl localhost returned the html. And I have not made any changes to the Security Group.
In browser when l load my site, the static pages load fine but dynamic pages do not load.
And in phpmyadmin, the login page loads but when I try to login, either it reloads the same page (with token added to the url) or loads the timeout page

Comment: If some pages load (eg static) and others don't (dynamic), then it would be a configuration on your web server rather than an AWS configuration.

Comment: Yea, and I finally figured out the issue. "clientmqueue" folder was taking up all of my disk space. I cleared the folder and now the dynamic pages are loading fine. Also, I am able to access phpmyadmin :). Now I need to find out why that folder was being filled up.